# Why is my Powershell script to sign a jar not executing properly?

Tags: powershell, jar, certificate, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Wrote this powershell script to try to sign a jar file. After building the proper command it basically looks like this:

```
$command = "jarsigner -storetype pkcs12 -keystore $certToUse -signedjar $nameOfSignedJar $nameOfJarToSign $defaultAlias"
Write-Output $command
Invoke-Expression $command
```

The Write-Output line prints out:

```
jarsigner -storetype pkcs12 -keystore MyCertificate.p12 -signedjar signed_sample.jar sample.jar "this is my test alias, inc.'s comodo ca limited id"
```

However when Invoke-Expression runs it basically just hangs and nothing else happens. If I run this exact command in powershell, I'm prompted for the password and then my JAR file is signed.

What am I doing wrong and how can I make it so that when it asks me for password and then I can pass it in through the same script?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Might be an issue with the unescaped quote in your $default alias:

```
$defaultalias = "`"this is my test alias, inc.`'s comodo ca limited id`""
```

Comment: The example you gave gives me an error in PowerShell ISE.
I'm escaping the single quote using double single quotes like so:



$defaultAlias = '"this is my test alias, inc.''s comodo ca limited id"'

Comment: Unexpected token 's' in expression or statement. The editor marks it as wrong.

Comment: The problem was the single quote treating ` as a character rather than as escape. Updated the answer

Comment: Well that fixes the ISE syntax error but it still hangs after I execute the command, same as was happening before. The printed command looks perfectly fine (same as the one I posted). I wonder if jar signing just isn't allowed through a script or something? Can't think of any other reason why I'm not being prompted for a password.

Comment: Resolved the issue. It seems to be an issue with running the script in ISE. I ran the script outside of the ISE and it worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the issue lies with PowerShell ISE. Running the script via powershell directly works perfectly fine.